# How would one country purchase another?

Tags: united-states, foreign-policy, greenland

Recently, the Trump administration [expressed interest in purchasing Greenland](https://www.euronews.com/2019/08/16/trump-has-privately-talked-about-us-purchase-of-greenland-sources). How exactly would this work? I would assume voters in both countries would be on board? Who would the payment go to if the Greenland government doesn’t exist after the purchase? Are there any historical examples of this?

Comment: Greenland is not a country, it’s a Danish territory.

Comment: Stormblessed I think my point is that's not clear Denmark could sell Greenland without Greenland's permission. So in a sense Greenland would be selling itself.

Comment: Are there historical examples? Yes there are lots of examples for buying territory off of other countries. Alaska, the Falklands,...

Comment: and the Louisiana purchase.

Comment: Related: [*When was the last time a country acquired territory by buying land from another country?*](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/54154/1392).

Comment: Comments deleted. The exact legal status of Greenland is an interesting topic, but only tangentially relevant to this question. If you have any questions about the exact relationship between Denmark and Greenland, please open a new question.

Comment: [Denmark sold the Virgin Islands to USA in 1917](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Virgin_Islands#Danish_period).

Comment: Perhaps Queen Elizabeth would like to buy it. Alaska.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Rather than focus on Greenland, it may be helpful to focus on a previous case where the US purchased a significant piece of land from another country. A nice example is [the Alaska Purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_Purchase). From the linked Wikipedia page:

> The Alaska Purchase (Russian: Продажа Аляски, tr. Prodazha Alyaski, Sale of Alaska) was the United States' acquisition of Alaska from the Russian Empire. Alaska was formally transferred to the United States on October 18, 1867, through a treaty ratified by the United States Senate and signed by President Andrew Johnson.

As for the Russian side of the purchase, Wikipedia states:

> In November 2018 a documentary ("SRF bi de Lüt") by the Swiss television broadcast the information that the Russian Tsar in 1867 had first proposed the sale of Alaska to the Prince of Liechtenstein, and that only after the prince rejected, Alaska was offered to the United States. German newspaper Welt am Sonntag reported similar facts earlier, in 2015.[36] The information was vividly discussed in Liechtenstein, and media there first portrayed it as a rumor. However, some days afterwards prince Hans-Adam II personally intervened in the discussion by writing a letter to the media in Liechtenstein, in which he assured that the alleged Alaska purchase offer was not a rumor, and that it was repeatedly a topic of discussion within the princely family in the past. Moreover he showed himself optimistic that archive searches might bring about (so far lacking) historical documents proving that the offer was real.

Based on that, it seems that Russia (the selling party) offered Alaska to the United States and the United States agreed to buy it.

---

In the Greenland example, the situation is different because [Denmark has stated](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/08/18/greenland-belongs-to-greenland-denmark-says-selling-worlds-largest-island-to-us-is-absurd.html) Greenland is not for sale. Greenland is an autonomous country of the Kingdom of Denmark, so for a transaction like the Alaska Purchase to happen they would have to agree to the sale.

Comment: Another example is the Louisiana Purchase: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louisiana_Purchase

Comment: Or much earlier: Manhattan Island was purchased by Dutch colonists from Native Americans in 1626. https://www.newnetherlandinstitute.org/history-and-heritage/additional-resources/dutch-treats/peter-schagen-letter/

Comment: [Purchase of the United States Virgin Islands, 1917](https://2001-2009.state.gov/r/pa/ho/time/wwi/107293.htm) from Denmark.

Comment: And Manhattan Island (New Amsterdam) was then exchanged for Pulau Run in 1677 : https://www.ft.com/content/a3afe44c-769e-11e7-a3e8-60495fe6ca71

Comment: Buying a piece of a country ignores one of the main points of the question, which is that there would be no government to receive the payment once the country is acquired.

Comment: @scatter That seems to be true if you buy an entire country. But if you just buy a part of a country, the country in which it was contained still has a government to receive the payment.

Comment: @Barmar: Sounds like final settlement of a deeply indebted government to me.

Comment: @scatter Why can't there be a government that doesn't control any land? It's not unheard of, e.g. a government-in-exile during wartime. As long as it exists as entity, it be good enough. It could pay the money to the (former) citizens, then dissolve.

Comment: @Sjoerd Another example of one country selling to other what is currently a state on he buying country is [Acre State on Brazil, bought from Bolivia on 1903](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acre_(state)#History)

Comment: [Trump cancelled his visit scheduled for 2019-09-02 over this](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-49416740).

Comment: I believe it is worth adding that according to §20 of the Danish constitution for Denmark to agree to a sale would require either a referendum or a 5/6 majority in parliament. (In case you're wondering, yes, that was written with sale of a territory in mind.)

Answer (score 52):

The question rightfully points out the democratic issues in such a process.

It's worth mentioning that the concept of a territory transaction between two countries is quite out of date under modern standards. This was a common practice in history when land was considered as a commodity, often incidentally considering the inhabitants themselves as a commodity as well. An important aspect of modern international law is [the right of a people to self-determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-determination). The concept of a country "owning" a territory (which is the basis for a transfer of ownership) is at odds with this now well established principle.

Nowadays, nobody (well, nobody sane) denies the legitimacy of the [massive decolonization process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decolonization) during the XXth century. This shows quite clearly why a country doesn't "own" its territories anymore: otherwise why would a colonial power give up ownership without any compensation? Even if the "owner" agrees on a deal, and even if the inhabitants validate the transaction democratically, the next generation of inhabitants would still be entitled to claim independence... Obviously this defeats the concept of ownership.

The concept of ownership of a inhabited territory implies that inhabitants have no say in who their land belongs to. It is rooted in a vision of the world where territories can be controlled by force, and it's worth noting that the concept of slavery is not so distant from this vision.

The Trump administration seems to assume that money buys everything. As an illustration, [Jared Kushner's Middle East peace plan](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2019/03/28/remember-jared-kushners-middle-east-peace-plan/) was also based on giving economic incentives to the Palestinians so that they abandon the land they claim. This is a serious misunderstanding of the deep cultural attachment most people have with their land, and how much it's part of their history and their identity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97707/discussion-on-answer-by-erwan-how-would-one-country-purchase-another).

Comment: This answer is bizarre and completely at odds with reality.  The United States has a number of territories which are part of the United States, but are not states.  Puerto Rico and Washington DC are among them.  The Federal government establishes the procedures which governs those territories, but their political offices are usually filled through elections.

Comment: @grovkin fyi the answer doesn't contradict the fact that historically some territories have been acquired by countries militarily or by transaction, and that many of these territories are still part of the country. Puerto Rico is an interesting example: I'm not sure that it would be acceptable nowadays to include a new territory without giving its inhabitants the same rights as other citizens.

Answer (score 29):

If both Greenland and Denmark agree to the deal, then the matter would be simple. Simply transfer Greenland to USA, like it happened with the Dansk Vestindien/Virgin Islands.

But even without Denmark's approval, this could happen in 3 steps.

1. USA would offer Greenland perhaps 150000 USD to each Greenlander, plus yearly subsidies. Half now, half later. This would create support in the population for the deal. However, no treaties would be signed since Greenland is not sovereign.
2. Then Greenland would declare independence from Denmark, something they are free to do according to Denmark.
3. After that, Greenland and USA would be free to merge their countries, even without anything but a promise from USA. Greenland would not be able to survive on its own.

Comment: I know it's just an example, but "$150,000 to each Greenlander" is nearly $8.5bn, and that's without the subsidies. That's an awfully high price to convince Congress to pay. Trump only wanted about half that for his border wall and (IIRC) he never received it.

Comment: A fair value for Greenland is probably 50 bn USD, so it would be a great deal for US.

Comment: If you could provide a source for that figure, it would be a lot convincing. I know Greenland's a big place, but I don't see any reason it would even be worth the $8.5bn, let along $50bn. It's 2 million sq.km of frozen nothing.

Comment: And what's to say the population follows through? Why not take half and stick with Denmark? After all, they have little assurance that they will get the other half after the deal is done.

Comment: This author tried to estimate a fair price https://www.nextbigfuture.com/2019/08/usa-wants-to-buy-greenland-and-a-fair-value-price-would-be-30-70-billion.html?amp

Comment: I *really* doubt Trump or Congress would offer half in advance.  It would all be promises of future riches.  Some of these promises might be honoured, some might not.

Comment: *This would create support in the population for the deal.* : I doubt that part. But we will never know until the USA really makes such an offer. So, we will never know.

Comment: Considering that +3-4 degree warming by the end of the century is likely now, I imagine it is potentially worth more like 500+ billion to a country like the USA. There is a lot of potential there. It is worth at least one years military budget, probably a few of them.

Comment: @MikeWise Sure, the ice might retreat. But we already think that Greenland is actually a collection of islands beneath all that ice, and there will be significant flooding associated with the warming (though I'm not sure where your +4 by the end of century comes from; is that supposed to be in Fahrenheit?). And the land will not be suitable for much use right away; I doubt there's much land anywhere in the world that's going to increase in some absolute value; at best, other lands will drop in value faster :P (not that it makes much of a difference, mind)

Comment: One reason for the valuation of Greenland that has not been mentioned yet is the territorial claim on part of the Arctic ocean. Given the oil reserves thought to be there, this claim would be of tremendous value.

Comment: @Ryebread Thanks for finding that source, your numbers do indeed seem a lot more convincing now. I'd suggest adding that information into your answer.

Comment: @Ryebread 50 is still low... Considering the huge oil and natural gas reserves, rare-earth metals, uranium and a whole bunch of other ores (nickel, copper, zinc, silver, platinum) in the coastal zones that we already know about. And the even more abundant resources that are expected to be found inland and will become accessible as the ice recedes.

Comment: The current subsidies are [4,3 giga DKK (0.6 giga USD)](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B8nland), corresponding to  77,000 DKK (11,000 USD) per Greenlander per year.

Comment: @Tonny: It can [already be done](https://www.kitco.com/news/2019-07-09/Proposed-Rare-Earth-Mine-In-Greenland-Claims-Lowest-Capital-Intensity.html). Only some [investors (with deep pockets)](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2013-02-10/chinese-workers-in-greenland) are needed (though geo politics). There is political stability, unlike some other countries. Some older mines were closed (zinc and [gold](https://www.kitco.com/news/video/show/Swiss-Mining-Institute-Conference/2189/2018-11-23/Greenland-The-Land-Of-The-Yellow-Metal) at least) because they were not economically viable.

Comment: New mines for [zinc, lead](https://www.arctictoday.com/greenland-lead-and-zinc-mine-approved-for-operation/), [uranium, and rare earth](https://www.mining.com/greenland-closer-building-worlds-fifth-largest-uranium-mine/) may be built (and gold, rubies, diamonds, nickel, and copper).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I didn’t say that iit couldn’t br done. Just that I considered the 50 bln. to be too low.

Comment: @Luaan: Re: "we already think that Greenland is actually a collection of islands beneath all that ice": But we've mapped the entire coastline; wouldn't we *know* if it weren't actually a single island? (Do you have a source that elaborates on your statement?)

Comment: @ruakh I'm not saying all the explorers were stupid :P It very much looks like an island from the outside - the coastline isn't uninterrupted, but close enough. However, as you go inland, the land beneath the ice goes way below sea level; if the ice melts, you'll either split Greenland into about three big islands, or form a massive inland lake. And that's before accounting for the sea level rise associated with all that ice (estimated around 7 meters or so). Of course, much of that depression is due to the weight of the ice sheet, so it might spring back above (current) sea level eventually.

Comment: @Luaan the southern part of Britain is still springing up from the last time it was covered by glaciers, so "eventually" will be quite some time in the future, like tens of thousands of years.

Answer (score 4):

Such purchases have happened, if we count purchases of colonies as fitting the description.

The USA bought territory from France (the Louisiana purchase), Russia (Alaska) and Denmark (The US Virgin Islands). These might not count as the purchases of *countries* as they were all sold by colonial powers who needed the money more than the territory and the colonies didn't have much say in the event. In principle this *could* happen with Greenland, but it is a sovereign territory with significant autonomy and the world has changed a lot since 1917 (the last time Denmark sold a colony).

The purchase of whole countries is less common if mergers are not considered (Europe has seen many countries effectively merge for a time through dynastic marriages, though not recently.)

But other forms of merger are known. England and Scotland had shared a monarch since 1603 (with a glitch for Cromwell's commonwealth mid century). But the countries remained separate. They were merged in 1706/7 partially because the Scottish government had nearly bankrupt itself in an ill fated colonial adventure in Panama. A major cause of the Acts of Union, which effectively merged the countries, was the need of Scotland to be bailed out by the richer England. If we allow mergers to count, this is, in effect, one country buying another (by mutual consent). Though that consent has been strained in recent years.

But the idea of countries agreeing to sell territory to others is much less popular in a world where democracy and the people's consent counts for something. And the USA has consent problems of its own with territories it has previous acquired but never properly incorporated into the union (Puerto Rico was acquired from Spain in the treaty that ended the Spanish-American war but still doesn't have the rights of a US state despite a population larger than about 20 of the 50 states).

Comment: Puerto Rico doesn’t unambiguously want to be a state.

Answer (score 3):

#### Regarding the historical examples

I would like to point your attention to the fact that even in the 18/19th century these transactions were not normal. They were mostly motivated by the desire to get at least some money before someone else takes the land by force. None of these territories has been sold for exclusively pecuniary reasons.

If you look at the supposed precedents mentioned in the other answers and comments:

- **Louisiana Purchase:** *"Napoleon needed peace with the United Kingdom to implement the Treaty of San Ildefonso and take possession of Louisiana. Otherwise, Louisiana would be an **easy prey for the UK or even for the United States**. But in early 1803, continuing war between France and the UK seemed unavoidable."* (from [Lousiana Purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louisiana_Purchase))
- **Virgin Islands:** *"Concerned about recent events and Danish recalcitrance, Lansing implied that **if Denmark was unwilling to sell, the United States might occupy the islands** to prevent their seizure by Germany."* (from [Purchase of the United States Virgin Islands, 1917](https://2001-2009.state.gov/r/pa/ho/time/wwi/107293.htm))
- **Manhattan:** In this case the question seems to be, if the sellers were even aware of what they were selling (and also if they were entitled to do so). ([Was Manhattan Really Bought for $24?](https://mentalfloss.com/article/12657/was-manhattan-really-bought-24))
- **Acre:** This territory wasn't sold - but conquered. Bolivia had lost the Acre War against Brazil and was forced to cede Acre in the [Treaty of Petrópolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Petr%C3%B3polis), even if it was promised a monetary compensation (which was actually paid).
- **Florida:** Spain didn't give up Florida seeing it as a simple monetary transaction either. After the Napoleonic Wars Spanish authority in Florida was practically non-existant. In 1818 Jackson invaded Florida as Spain could not prevent Seminole attacks or the escape of slaves from Georgia. While not at war with Spain, the US army still captured several Spanish forts. One year later Spain signed the [Transcontinental Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adams%E2%80%93On%C3%ADs_Treaty) (or Adams-Onís-Treaty; ratified in 1821). A monetary compensation - which wasn't paid, but used to settle claims by US citizens - was part of the treaty, but it was also about the border in Texas. Spain obtained an US recognition of its sovereignty in Texas, while giving up a territory, which it no longer controlled.
- **Alaska**: Financial difficulties in Russia, **the desire to keep Alaska out of British hands**, and the low profits of trade with Alaskan settlements all contributed to Russia's willingness to sell its possessions in North America. ([History_of_Alaska#Alaska_purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Alaska#Alaska_purchase))

Comment: Regarding Manhattan, Russell Shorto makes a convincing case in *The Island at the Center of The World* that the buyers also misunderstood what they were buying.  Mutual land-use agreements were apparently common between different tribes, and the "sellers" probably understood the agreement in those terms.

Comment: @phoog: Exactly, that's what I meant with "what they were selling". It's in the last section of my source: *law professor G. Edward White interprets the Manhattan “sale” from the Indians' point of view as “not relinquishing the island, but simply welcoming the Dutch as additional occupants,” [..]*

Comment: Right, but the focus on the misunderstanding of the native people implies that the colonists were somehow correct about the transaction and/or the natives were duped because of their lack of sophistication.  In fact, the misunderstanding was on both sides.  The colonists were just as clueless.

Comment: @phoog: Okay, now I see your point. I think that the current answer is still correct. If you want to make it clear that Peter Stuyvesant and the other colonsits didn't act in ill faith, feel free to do so. (Please no treatise.)

Comment: I have no idea whether they acted in bad faith.  I suppose its likely that they didn't; that it was an innocent misunderstanding.  But it bears mention that such misunderstandings require at least two parties to be mistaken. So it affects the correctness of the answer to the extent that whether Manhattan was sold depends on both parties' understanding, while the answer only considers the possibility that the sellers were mistaken about the nature of the transaction.  Why should we defer to the buyers' understanding over the sellers'?

Answer (score 2):

If by this

> one country purchase a country

you mean as a legal transaction of acquiring an **entire** territory (not just a part of land) and **claim sovereignty**, no I don't think that has happened and can happen in the current structure and order of the world.

Maybe in some twist of things (imagine an end-of-the-world scenario where there is threat to our existence), a new world order will legally allow selling of one country to another, then maybe.

Comment: There is an interpretation where the Acts of Union which formed the United Kingdom of England and Scotland was exactly that, in that England paid off Scotland's debt, and in return a new entity was formed, run from the site of the old English parliament.

Comment: The Act of Union (1707) formed the [Kingdom of Great Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Great_Britain) @origimbo. The earlier one was repealed.

Comment: @mOchi, perhaps the USA acquiring Greenland from Denmark is possible in the same way that Russia acquired Crimea from the Ukraine in 2014.  The important thing is to have support of the inhabitants of the area, and/or lots of soldiers.

Answer (score 1):

In modern history, the accession of [Newfoundland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_Act) to Canada is somewhat (with a big grain of salt) an example of this. Newfoundland, being basically broke, joined Canada, with the federal government assuming responsibility for the debts. Note that Newfoundland had been a dominion (thus reasonably independent) before, but voluntarily (and temporarily) changed itself into UK colony in 1933, because of dire state of its finances. This being modern times, everything was within democratic framework, with a referendum approving joining Canada.

Answer (score 0):

The United States has bought portions of it's territory 3 times in it's history:  Louisiana (France, much larger portion of the country than the state... it doubled the U.S. size by land over night), Florida (Spain), and Alaska (Russia).  In the case of Alaska and Louisiana, both deals were initiated by the seller, not the buyer.  LA Territory financed Napoleon's wars while Alaska was becoming a fiscal burden to Russia (ironically, it's now one of the richest states in the United States).

Florida is weird (as per frickin' usual) but Spain had a problem policing the U.S./Spainish Florida border and Americans were coming in and living there (not to mention that the English had previously controlled it and ceded it back to Spain following the Revolutionary War).  Eventually, the American and English Settlers seceded from Spain, and formed the "Republic of West Florida" or as I prefer to refer to it, "Floridamanistan".  And with a name like that, one shouldn't be surprised that West Florida was a nation for 90 days and was finally annexed by the U.S.  Spain would also lose disputed territory to the United States over where the LA purchase set the borders, some of the territory being taken by states on Florida's border... and it was hard for Spain to properly defend the territory... So they finally sold the whole state just to be rid of the headache of Florida (In a deal that is best described as "A bunch of Andrew Jackson's thugs holding the Spanish Ambassador at gun point and saying "Wanna sell us one Florida?").  Florida entered U.S. control in much the same way that it does everything else:  Some combination of money and stupid and general weirdness that the rest of the country just threw their hands up and said, "Why do we have them again?"

Does this mean Trump is going to hold the Danish Ambassador at gunpoint over Greenland?  Probably not... but he does like to vacation in Florida so... I mean...  I'm not totally convinced yet

Comment: Also the [Gadsden Purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadsden_Purchase) from Mexico.

Comment: I'm honestly not familiar with that one.   I used to live in Florida, so it's a bit easier to comment on the oddities.

Comment: @RickSmith indeed. Also, as others have pointed out, the US Virgin Islands, which were acquired from none other than Denmark.